# Probability (Intro to mathematical statistics)

Tags: probability

Let $C_1$ , $C_2$ and $C_3$ be 3 mutually disjoint subsets of the sample space **C** , we need to find P[($C_1\cup C_2$)$\cap$$C_3$] and P($\not C_1\cup $$\not C_2$) { $C_1$ not union $C_2$ not } .

What I figured out ... :

Since , $C_1$ , $C_2$ and $C_3$ are mutually disjoint , $C_1\cup C_2$ and $C_3$ are disjoint too , so P[($C_1\cup C_2$)$\cap$$C_3$] = $\phi$ ,

Second one is actually a guess , I tried this with the help of a venn diagram and thus got P($\not C_1\cup $$\not C_2$) = P[$C_3$$\cup$($ \not C_3\cap$**C**)].

Are these solutions correct ?
HELP !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say $P((C_1 \cup C_2) \cap C_3) = 0$ instead of $\varnothing$. For the second, try to apply De Morgan's law:
$$P(C_1^c \cup C_2^c) = P((C_1 \cap C_2)^c) = 1 - P(C_1 \cap C_2) = 1 - 0 = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

You did the first one correct. We notate $C_1^c$ for what you call "not $C_1$". For the second questine we now see that $C_1^c = \mathbf{C} \setminus C_1$ and $C_2^c= \mathbf{C} \setminus C_2$. Thus $$P( C_1^c \cap C_2^c) = P((\mathbf{C} \setminus C_1) \cap (\mathbf{C} \setminus C_2))= P((\mathbf{C} \cap (C_1)^c) \cup (\mathbf{C} \cap (C_2)^c))$$
Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are disjoint we see that this is $\mathbf{C}$.